# Passing input parameters to class attributes

Tags: python

I'm devloping a module that works with another module. The other module requires class attributes to be set before the `__init__` method (let's work under the assumption that the behavior of this other module cannot be changed). These class attributes (`Signal` in the example below) are derived partially from an object that comes from my code.

The method shown below is a disaster for many reasons. For example,

1. `my_obj1` and `my_obj2` are not guaranteed to exist; the 
   import in the other module will fail in this case.
2. There could be a need to create 2 different instances of 
   `OtherModuleVodoo1` using 2 different instances from my code 
   (`my_obj`).

This is a skeleton of the code to explain:

````
import Signal, Device
from my_module.setup import my_obj1, my_obj2

class OtherModuleVodoo1(Device):
    # The class signal attributes must be defined before the __init__ 
    # and rely upon an object from my module

    x = Signal(my_obj1.cmds['thing_x'], 'thing_x')
    y = Signal(my_obj1.cmds['thing_y'], 'thing_y')

    # ...
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class OtherModuleVodoo2(Device):
    x = Signal(my_obj2, 'thing1')
    y = Signal(my_obj2, 'thing2')

    # ...
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# now in my file I do this
dev1 = OtherModuleVodoo1()
dev2 = OtherModuleVodoo2()

# but would much prefer to do this 
dev1 = OtherModuleVodoo(my_object_input = my_obj1)
# where I don't need ```Vodoo1, Vodoo2``` but can have a generic 
solution.
````

### Question:

Is there a way to "input" parameters to the construction of a class (not to the initialization of a class instance)?

### What I tried and why each did not work.

1. Metaclasses. These feel close to the right approach but I wasn't able to get it to work.
2. `__new__` but this doesn't populate the namespace within the class definition (before the `__init__`)
3. Setting `my_obj1 = None` until an `OtherModuleVodoo1` instance is needed and then modifying the class attribute before instantiating an object:

An example of attempt 3:

```
xyq = None
class Test2():
    print(xyq)
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.xyq)

Test2.xyq = 55
t2 = Test2()
```

However, here the output is:

```
None
55
```

I anticipate responses that focus completely on changing the approach. That is warranted. However, my immediate question is how to best band-aid what I have.

Comment: Metaclasses can modify the class before its creation, but only once per class definition and only on code startup. Is that OK?

Comment: That would be OK and would get me much closer to a reasonable solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may need some massaging to make it work with your code, but you can use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__)  in a parent class to accept arguments to class creation.  This was introduced in Python 3.6

```
class Voodoo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, myobj, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.x = Signal(my_obj1.cmds['thing_x'], 'thing_x')
        cls.y = Signal(my_obj1.cmds['thing_y'], 'thing_y')

class Voodoo1(Voodoo, Device, myobj=myobj1):
    pass
```

You could also make `Voodoo` a `Device` subclass to clean up the signatures of your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Example with a metaclass in Python 3:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        dct['xyq'] = 55

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    ... # A.xyq == 55

class B(A):
    ... # B.xyq == A.xyq == 55
```

The metaclass takes action when the classes A and B are *created* (not *instantiated*).